# How do I pass a Redux action created by Redux Toolkit's createSlice to a screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, redux-toolkit

In my React Native app I have a generic settings screen that presents users with a question, and a list of options. The question and options are passed to the screen as navigation params (I am using react-navigation v5 and the useNavigation and useRoute hooks).

I want this settings screen to update my redux state when the user clicks on an option. However, the action to be dispatched should be dynamic based on the question being asked. I have a series of actions generated via Redux Toolkit's createSlice. I have exported these actions like so:

`export const { changeColorScheme, changeDefaultUnits } = slice.actions;`

I initially tried to pass these actions as navigation params to the settings screen, but got the "Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state" warning.

I have since tried to pass the action name as a navigation prop, and in the settings screen I tried dispatching the action with

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const route = useRoute();
[...]
dispatch({
  type: route.params.actionName, // eg "changeColorScheme"
  payload: theOptionTheUserSelected // eg "dark"
})
```

This latter method does not seem to trigger the action/reducer at all. I wonder if there's something to do with how Redux Toolkit creates and exports actions that means they cannot be dispatched in this manner?

Am I missing something? Is there another way to potentially achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that warning, I assume that React-Navigation's "navigation state" is actually kept in the Redux store. [You should not put non-serializable values like functions into the store state](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions), so RTK warns about that.

For the dispatch issue, this is an excellent time to use the Redux DevTools to review what actions are being dispatched, including what the specific action type strings are.

Note that action types generated by `createSlice` are strings that have two parts, based on the slice name and the reducer name.  So, instead of `"changeColorScheme"`, it *probably* needs to be something like `"settings/changeColorScheme"`.  Be sure to use the value from the action creator's `type` field, like `changeColorScheme.type`, to have the right value here.

Comment: You are an absolute legend. To confirm, you were correct in saying the name had to be `settings/actionName`, and that this was accessible from the action's type property. Also, just to add, my understanding from the docs is that react-navigation does indeed use redux behind the scenes. Thanks again.